# Passing data between tabs of UITabBar

Tags: ios, swift

[Storyboard screenshot with description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2VqX.jpg)

I've used this line of code in the `UIViewController` class of 2nd tab to access the `tabBarViewController`. But it crashes.

```
let friendView = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![2] as! AccountTableViewController
```

**Note:** `AccountTableViewController` is the name of `UITableViewController` class of 3rd tab.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: is your `AccountTableViewController` embed with `NavigationController`?

Comment: You shouldn't be accessing a view controller from another view controller. Both view controllers should be accessing a shared model instead: one should write the data, and the other should read it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Do you mean `NSUserDefaults`?

Comment: @p.yarandi No, that is not what I mean. I mean the model as in [Model-View-Controller pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH14), which is central to developing apps with user interface.

Comment: @p.yarandi Is your AccountTableViewController Contains navigationController?

Comment: @p.yarandi Check my answer.

Comment: @Nirav Yes, both of views (2nd & 3rd) have ` NavigationController ` But your answer didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code like this

```
let navController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![2] as! UINavigationController
for vc in (self.navigationController?.viewControllers)! {
    if (vc.isKindOfClass(AccountTableViewController.classForCoder())) {
        let friendView = vc as! AccountTableViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: It crashes again :(

Comment: @p.yarandi Show your storyboard pic that will be helpful.

Comment: I added it to my question.

Comment: Please set the language to english or add text inside your image with viewController name

Comment: I determined `AccountTableViewController` on new screenshot

Comment: Yessss. Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome, Happy Coding :)