# Passing data from a tab bar switch right into another view controller

Tags: swift, firebase, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

**The question might sound complicated, so let me ease the stress***

- Lets say I have 2 tab bar tabs (Home1, Home2)
- Both (Home1, Home2) have navigational controllers with two view controllers each
- Home1(Navigation controller -> VC11 -> VC12)
- Home2 (Navigation controller -> VC21 -> VC22)

**Easy right? Well, not quite**

**What I want to do is pass data from [Home1: VC12 to Home2: VC22].**

My coding efforts:

```
tabBarController!.selectedIndex = 1
self.navigationController!.popToViewController(navigationCon‌troller!.viewControl‌​lers[1] as! (Home2: VC22), animated: false)



let navController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![1] as! UINavigationController
navController.popToViewController((Home2: VC22) as! UIViewController, animated: true)

for oneView in (self.navigationController?.viewControllers)! {
    if (oneView.isKind(of: (Home2: VC22).classForCoder())) {
      let friendView = oneView as! (Home2: VC22)
      friendView.testing = "Worked?"
    }
}
```

**ANYHELP IS WELCOMED!! Total hours spent: 8hrs**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pass data task is going though this process

**V12 --(pop)--> V11 --(switch)--> V21 --(push)--> V22**

If you choose to pass data, you will need to pass it though all these three transactions and that's lots of coding and it's hard to practice.

Instead of passing data around, a better way to accomplish your goal is to store the data in V12, and then load it from V22. So now all you need to worry about is how to transfer user from V12 to V22.

You only need two lines of code to store and read data from `UserDefaults`

On your V12, before you are doing the above transactions, first save your data like this

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("yourStringData", forKey: "data")
```

Then when you reach VC22, from `viewDidLoad`, read stored info in this way

```
UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "data")
```

For your view transaction part, `popToViewController` is for going from a child view controller to it's parent. So when you switch your tab and get the `UINavigationController`, the `topViewController` must be VC21. So to go to VC22 given that you connect them though a storyboard segue, simply call it like this

```
let navController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![1] as! UINavigationController
let VC21 = navController.topViewController!
VC21.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil)
```

Comment: I dont think it worked because received data never gets called with breakpoints

Comment: @24hrcoder As I said, you need to make sure the destination view controller is valid. If it hasn't been initiated or is already poped out of you navigation controller, this this wont work. Do you want to pass data even if the destination view controller is not inited?

Comment: Yes, even if it isn't initiated. How could I do it then?

Comment: @24hrcoder One last question before I update my answer man. When the pass data event is triggered from your source view controller, do you want your app to pop out your source view controller, switch tab, populate your destination view controller in order to pass the data? Or you just want this data to be available when user opens the destination view controller?

Comment: I will love for it to pop out source view, switch tabs and populate my destination view controller. thks

Comment: @24hrcoder One last question again... Since I don't know the structures of your view controllers, can you do the switch, populate correctly? Or that part is failing too? Any error messages or?

Comment: I tried thousands of ways, but I was unable to get to Home2: VC22. If you could help me with the switch, that would be perfect

Comment: @24hrcoder Okay. From VC111 to VC12, are you using a push segue, modal segue, or calling `present` ?

Comment: When I push from [Home1: VC12] to [Home2: VC21]- I am able to pop the [Home1: VC12] and present [Home2: VC21] using "tabBarController!.selectedIndex = 1" . I have succeeded to passing data

Comment: I have not* succeeded in passing data

Comment: So there's no way for me to push to VC22?

Comment: @24hrcoder Sure there is. How do you connect VC21 to VC22 noramally? Through a segue inside storyboard?

Comment: Yes sir, VC21 has a nav controller and connects via segue to VC22

Comment: could you allow me a few moments to test this functionality

Comment: let test3 = tabBarController?.viewControllerstabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2;                
        let test = tabBarController?.selectedViewController;
        let test2 = test?.presentedViewController;
        let test5 = test2?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "actualmessagesegue", sender: self);

Comment: performSegue never gets called: Test3 returns all tab bar controllers, test returns the one I picked, test2 returns nil

Comment: it does transition to VC21 but doesn't do the segue to VC22?? Any Tips??

Comment: @24hrcoder Updated answer. You need to call `performSegue` on `topViewController` of your navigation controller. Think about your navigation controller as a shell and it need something on top of it to display for users. In this case, the `topViewController` is VC21.

Comment: I tried it over and over and the prepare for segue never gets called and the console displays no errors

Comment: I am not able to comment on this thread but this person made it work, I tried implementing this approach with no success: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609589/passing-data-between-tabs-of-uitabbar

Answer (score 0):

You could also subclass your tabbar and create a variable to store your data there.  Then both VC's would have access to the data.  This way also alleviates the possible need for a singleton.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Jerland2, but it might go a little deeper than singletons sir

Comment: @24hrcoder my proposed solution is one that DOES NOT involve singletons.  My solution is one I have used multiple times for a nearly identical issue without  using singletons

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to rethink your approach. It depends on the way you setup your app but it makes sense to store this data somewhere else besides directly passing it from one VC to another. Here are some options:

1. Singleton that stores your data and you pass that around from one VC to another so that if **VC12** stores data in the Singleton, then **VC22** can access it easily since it also has access to the singleton.
2. Have the *Container* View Controller store the data to be shared amongst its children view controllers. So, in this example, the **TabBarController** can store this data.
3. Use **UserDefaults** as a poor-mans Singleton/Persistence solution.
4. Use a full blown Data Persistence layer using SQLite, Core Data, or Realm for example to store and retrieve data.

... there are others but I think one of these solutions can work well for you depending on your needs.

Comment: Thank you Guillermo for the reply, but I might be up to something with Mr. Fang